# macOS Sonoma Dock Web Apps - Open URL in Dock App?

Tags: macos, macos-sonoma

I'm experimenting with the new macOS Sonoma Dock Apps using an internally developed website at our company. It works great for creating a container for the website however when I click a link in an email with a link to the website, Safari still launches.

Is it possible to redirect specific website links to a Dock App? I've been trying to make this work in Shortcuts.app but it seems more suited for URL schemes rather than specific site URLs.

Thanks!